# WebGLRenderingContext's texImage2D and texSubImage2D function

Tags: webgl

I have a one question about WebGLRenderingContext's texImage2D and texSubImage2D function. 
What I trying to create is something similar like loading image by tile by tile.

Here is my first function. It's working properly while it's first load. But whenever loading second time using same function but tiled background.
It failed. Look at the code below

// This is first load code which is working fine

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
```

// This is second time using same but one different coding section [image data from canvas]. But it's not working.

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, [image data from canvas])

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
```

Have you ever face the problem similar like me. Then please guide me to the light. Much appreciate it.

**UPD**

```
on('start', function (data) {

      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
      // gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, data.width, data.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvasData)
      gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, data.width, data.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(myCanvasData.buffer))

    }).on('progress', function (ev) {
      var x = ev.position[0]
      var y = texHeight - ev.position[1] - ev.image.height

      // now blit the intermediate image
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
      gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ev.image)

    }).on('complete', function () {
    })
```

[Console warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp9J7.png)

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console for errors? Without seeing the actual code for `[image data from canvas]` it's kind of suspicious. In other words please post that code too AND tell us if there's any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're probably using `texImage2D` wrong. The thing is, for `ImageData` [signature of the function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.8) is a bit different (it's the same as for am image):

```
void texImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat, GLenum format, GLenum type, TexImageSource? source),
```

where `TexImageSource` can be an `ImageData` object. So you just need to pass it, without explicitly passing width and height of the image:

```
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
    0, 
    gl.RGBA, 
    gl.RGBA, 
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    canvas.getImageData(/* ... */)
);
```

Comment: He could be doing `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_DATA, new Uint8Array(canvas.getImageData(...).data.buffer)));`?

Comment: Yes, he could. If that's the case, then my answer isn't appropriate:)

Comment: `gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
    0, 
    gl.RGBA, 
    gl.RGBA, 
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    canvas.getImageData(/* ... */)
);`
this code working but `texSubImage2D` function not working correctly. I think must passing width and height. Because without width and height `texSubImage2D` this function dont know size of canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like texImage2D without explicitly passing width and height. Because i think texSubImage2D function width and height requires thought

Answer (score 0):

```
on('start', function (data) {

      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
      // gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, data.width, data.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myCanvasData)
      gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, data.width, data.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(myCanvasData.buffer))

    }).on('progress', function (ev) {
      var x = ev.position[0]
      var y = texHeight - ev.position[1] - ev.image.height

      // now blit the intermediate image
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, handle)
      gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ev.image)

    }).on('complete', function () {
    })
```

[Console warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp9J7.png)